# How to print 8 copies of a one page LibreOffice document to 2 sheets of paper?

Tags: printing, libreoffice

When printing a multi-page document I can print four pages to a single sheet of paper. It prints, for example, pages 1-4 on one sheet and pages 5-8 on the next sheet. I have a one page LibreOffice document. How do I print eight copies to just two sheets of paper?

Comment: [How do I print say four copies of a document on a single sheet](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/34516/how-do-i-print-say-four-copies-of-a-document-on-a-single-sheet/) and do it twice. Make sure your page is formatted as A6 (so 4 copies fit on an A4 page) or the US equivalent ...

Comment: See also: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45701

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as I know how these printers work, we can have two solutions, I think.

1. when printing the document, instead of just print, use the print dialog and choose pages to print, you type `1,1,1,1` so it'll print 4 times the page one.
2. Repeat in the document the first page (at least 4 times, or 8 times if you want to print it at one).

Comment: Slaps head for not even thinking of 1,1,1,1!